# How to un-subscribe an item from a flux

Tags: project-reactor

Consider the following flux

```
FluxSink<String> sink;
Flux<String> flux1 = Flux
    .<String>create(emitter -> { 
         sink = emitter;
    },...)
    .cache()
    .publish()
    .autoConnect();
```

So to add/subscribe an item, we can do `sink.next(“4”);`

```
flux1.subscribe(item -> log.info(“item: “+item);
```

By filtering `flux1`, say from element “2” were not removing that item from the flux..
I know the `Flux` publisher is immutable.

If we can add to it via sink, how can we remove an item from `flux1`?

Answer (score 2):

## The proper thinking gives proper answers

Think about Flux as about immutable Stream of messages. It is like a river, you can add some water to it, but you can't roll back the water you have already given down the flow. However, you can filter that water down the stream.

In case you need to "remove" illegal elements from the stream, you can filter them:

```
flux1.filter(e -> !e.equal("2"))
     .subscribe(item -> log.info(“item: “+item);
```

The flux is not a data structure to which we got used to, but it is a stream of data, which you cannot modify at the point of data supply, but can manipulate the way they go to the endpoint

Comment: Lets say a server is running for indefinitely, it has a flux containing lets say new objects every hour.
On the next day, all elements from the day before are irrelevant.
Hence they should be garbage collected.
if they wont this server has a memory leak.

what am I missing here? 
flux1.filter doesn't garbage collect the new objects emitted, since the immutable flux1 has reference to them.